# Select Shipping method on cart page

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, shipping, shipping-methods

I'm just wondering if it's possible to allow a customer to select a shipping method on the cart/basket page without entering country or postcode? I have added an image of a mockup to show what it is I'm looking to do. If anyone knows a tutorial or extension that would do this that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't ship to different countries, or if you don't use the matrixrate extension, you can edit the estimate tax & shipping box to get this effect.

I've used this tutorial as a base:

http://www.arscommunity.com/wiki/magento/default-address-for-shipping-estimation

```
copy /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php
```

to

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php
```

and before:

```
$this->_quote = $quote;
```

add this

```
$sha = $quote->getShippingAddress();
if (!$sha->getCountry()) {
$country = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/country_id');
$state = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/region_id');
$postcode = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/postcode');
$quote->getShippingAddress()
->setCountryId($country)
->setRegionId($state)
->setPostcode($postcode)
->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$this->resetCheckout();
$quote->save();
}
```

then copy

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

to

```
/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

and change it, I've changed it to:

```
  <div class="shipping">
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?></h2>
<div class="shipping-form">



    <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): ?>
    <form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>">
        <dl class="sp-methods">
            <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?>
                           <?php else: ?>
                                <input name="estimate_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                                <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                    (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </label>
                           <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>" class="button" name="do" value="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: No, this hasn't worked for me. My shipping methods are not visible.

Comment: I've edited the two files, it should work now. I've added a reset in Session.php and removed the form fields in shipping.phtml 
I took the information from this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/194314/#t245813

Comment: Brilliant, I have this working. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: hi the above URL is not working
(magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/194314/#t245813)
I need to set select Shipping method option in cart page. Please help

Comment: I tried the above code  its not working.please help